# excel-js: Create a named range with a formula with relative reference (R1C1 notation)

Tags: office-js, exceljs

When trying to create a named range for a formula that uses relative reference. In R1C1 notation, it would be R[1]C[1]. But any possibility I tried gave me an absolute path. Even if I did "=Sample!B1", I would see a "=Sample!$B$1" created. 
Is there a way to create a relative reference named range, without reverting to INDIRECT or INDEX strategy?

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    sheet.names.add("RelativeCell", "=Sample!R[1]C[1]")
    await context.sync();
  });
```

Comment: What was your final solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

could you use a range object when you created a named range? 
You can use R1C1 notation for the range object.

```
range = sheet.getRange("A1:D1"); 
names.add("RelativeCell", range);
```

Comment: It's about the formula you are setting the named range with.

Comment: What is "names" in this context? I've tried setting "worksheet.names.add", but "name" is undefined in the worksheet object. Also in the workBook object.  What's the correct syntax here? Bottom line: how do you set a name for a range of sets in ExcelJs?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot do this, office-js always converts it to an absolute reference. A work-around is to "wrap" the reference in a function, such as this one:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:D1,1,4)
```

Note that you'll have to change the function, depending on which relative reference you want to achieve precisely.